# collectionView.cellForItem crashes

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

i'm using collectionView.cellForItem in the funciton call:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! PlaybookPlayCell
    ......
    ......
}
```

That is working fine. This tells me that the collection view setup is done correctly. 
BUT if i use collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) the function call sizeForItemAt i get a crash on the assignment of the cell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! PlaybookPlayCell // CRASH ON THIS LINE

    ...
    ...

    return CGSize(width: ...., height: ......)
}
```

Would be great to get some input. 
Thanks

Comment: It probably means the cell at that index path isn't a `PlaybookPlayCell`. The force cast `as!` will crash if the cast fails.

Comment: Agreed with @KaneCheshire also mentioned here the crash from debugger.

Comment: plz share your collection view all delegate and datasource methods

Comment: `cellForItem(at: indexPath)` returns nil if the cell is not visible. Also, I wouldn't call that method inside `collectionView(_colleciton:collectionViewLayout:sizeForItemAt:)`. Why do you need that?

Comment: Simple set your collection cell class to your collection view from your story board

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am calling `collectionView.cellForItem(at:)` from another function (to flip the image of the clicked cell) but the App crashes when I make the forced cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be always nil because `collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)` will be called before initialization of collection view(`collectionView.cellForRaw(at: indexPath)`). Set the breakpoints in both of them and you will see.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, never force unwrap optionals otherwise your app is liable to crash unexpectedly.

Replace

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! PlaybookPlayCell // CRASH ON THIS LINE
```

with:

```
guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? PlaybookPlayCell else {
    // This wasn't expected
    // return something
}
```

Then inside your 'else' clause you can add something to help you debug your issue. e.g.

```
let unexpected = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
```

Step to the line and take a look at 'unexpected'. Is it nil? Is it a different type? That should get you further with your issue.

Comment: This answer is an opinion and doesn't really help debug. In this particular case I'd argue it's good that the app is crashing - that's how the OP knows there is a problem in their code.